# Vine’s Infinite Video Loops in iOS 9 (seamlessly video)

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, video-streaming, avplayer

I need some help with Infinite Video Loops like a Vine did.
I tried a lot of approaches and all of them have a short delay.

One of most popular:

```
  __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self; // prevent memory cycle
  NSNotificationCenter *noteCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
 [noteCenter addObserverForName:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                    object:nil // any object can send
                     queue:nil // the queue of the sending
                usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                    // holding a pointer to avPlayer to reuse it
                    [weakSelf.avPlayer seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
                    [weakSelf.avPlayer play];
                }];
```

Is there any way to eliminate the delay and play local videos seamlessly?

I know that Apple add some updates in iOS 9, but I need that it work from 8+ ios

Sorry for Ojc-C sample, I use Swift

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(void)startPlaybackForItemWithURL:(NSURL*)url {

// First create an AVPlayerItem
AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];

// Subscribe to the AVPlayerItem's DidPlayToEndTime notification.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:playerItem];

// Pass the AVPlayerItem to a new player
self.avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

// Begin playback
[player play]

} 

-(void)itemDidFinishPlaying:(NSNotification *) notification {
    [self.avPlayer play];
    // Will be called when AVPlayer finishes playing playerItem
}
```